# compile and ran java project with terminal with one .jar file

Tags: java, jar, compilation, terminal, package

I created Myproject folder just for testing. Inside I have 3 folders: 
 /lib
 /src 
 /bin

Inside src there is this .java file:

```
public class hello_world{

     public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hi, from hello_world");

        seba.st.hello_world_package test1 = new seba.st.hello_world_package();

        test1.packFunc();
    }

}
```

inside lib is a .jar file which I created from this .java file:

```
    package seba.st;

public class hello_world_package{

    public void packFunc(){

        System.out.println("hi from pack_func!");
    }       
 }
```

I am trying to run this program from terminal with this command

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath src -cp lib/packEx.jar src/hello_world.java
```

and I get this error:

```
    src/hello_world.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        test1.packFunc();
             ^
  symbol:   method packFunc()
  location: variable test1 of type hello_world_package
1 error
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I compile and run this program from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Compile your project then try this instead:

```
javac -jar lib/packEx.jar
```

Comment: don't how to compile my project. Instead of what?